# store formdata field to local storage not working

Tags: angular, local-storage, angular7, formgroups

I am trying to append formGroup field to store in local storage so that i can get it on another page. My code is

.ts file is

```
   var u8Image  = b64ToUint8Array(b64Image);
const file = new File([u8Image], rString + '.jpg', { type: "image/jpeg", lastModified: Date.now() });
const clothsize = this.sizeForm.value.clothsize;
const quantity = this.sizeForm.value.quantity;
 var formData = new FormData();
 formData.append("image", file);
 formData.append('clothsize', clothsize);
 formData.append('quantity', quantity);
 formData.append('design', this.fileDesign);
 this.service.addToCart(formData)
 console.log('success')
```

service.ts is

```
  getCart(){
const formData = localStorage.getItem('formData');
return formData? JSON.parse(formData) : [];


 }

  addToCart(data) {
    const formData: Data[] = this.getCart();
    if (!formData) {
      this.setTodosIntoStore([data]);
    } else {
      formData.push(data);
      this.setTodosIntoStore(formData);
    }

}

setTodosIntoStore(formData: Data[]) {
  localStorage.setItem('formData', JSON.stringify(formData));
}
```

I got blank filed in local storage. Is there any way to save reactive formgroup data in local storage?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of converting formData to JSON :

```
localStorage.setItem('formData', JSON.stringify(formData));
```

Try to create an object from formData then convert it to Json like this :

```
localStorage.setItem('formData', JSON.stringify(Object.fromEntries(formData.entries())));
```

You said `fromEntries` not supported , then try :

```
let object = {};
formData.forEach(function(value, key){
    object[key] = value;
});
let json = JSON.stringify(object);

localStorage.setItem('formData', json);
```

Comment: fromEntries property is not supported

Comment: yes thankyou added  "dom.iterable" and it work on previous code

Comment: is it work with :   localStorage.setItem('formData', JSON.stringify(Object.fromEntries(formData.entries()))); ?

Answer (score 0):

An alternative would be to save the reactive form data into the local storage first and create formData from it later by getting from local storage, when you have to post it.

localStorage.setItem('data', JSON.stringify(this.sizeForm.value));